# Text Variables on Master Slide in InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

Currently I want to neatly organise a batch of 500 PDFs in one InDesign document. I placed them slide by slide into my document, and now I thought of adding a small box on the corner of each slide which indicates the names of the individual PDF files. I did this via the

Type > Text Variables > Insert Variable > **Image Name**

option. Adding the box and the variable to the master slide adds it on every page, but it does not "intersect" with the images/PDFs, thus it does not recognise the file names ("< No intersecting link >").

Is there another way to solve this, apart from adding the box with the variable to every page individually?

[image]

### Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Setup your text frame and variable in the master page
2. Select all existing pages in the pages panel
3. Right click and select **Override All Master Page Items** (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

Your text variables now behave as you want them to.

[image: Override All Master Page Items]

[image]

One thing to note, If you make any changes to the overridden items *in your document*, any changes you make to the *master* page won't be reflected in your document.

To get around this, all you need to do is select the affected page in the pages panel and **Apply Master to Pages...**. Then repeat the process of overriding to fix your variables.